# SQL : multiple table join for data extraction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables and i want a join to extract data from database.
So that i can get products with names with their category name.
here are three tables.

```
categories
```

contains `id`, `name`

```
category_product
```

contains `category_id` , `product_id`,

```
products
```

contains `id` , `name`, `price`.

now `products.id` is fkey in `category_product.product_id` AND `categories.id` is fkey in  `category_product.category_id`

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Please at least leave messages, or correct me if I'm wrong anywhere, downrating is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select c.name as category_name,p.name as product_name
from category_product cp
inner join categories c on cp.category_id=c.id
inner join products p on cp.product_id=p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

use join like below

```
select p.*,pc.*,c.* from product p join category_product pc on p.id= pc.product_id
join categories c on c.id=pc.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name AS product, c.name as category
from products p
inner join category_product cp on cp.product_id = p.id
inner join categories c on c.id = cp.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  products.name as 'Product Name',
    categories.name as 'Category Name',* 
    from category_product 
    inner join categories on category_product.category_id = categories.id
    inner join on products on category_product.product_id = products.id
order by categories.id
```